# FontAwesome css classes missing?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, font-awesome, tailwind-css

I'm using a very similar Next.js project setup where the FontAwesome CSS classes are working, the only real difference is that this project is using `Tailwindcss`, where my previous project was with `styled-components`

This is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "trpc-test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "rm -rf .next && prisma generate && next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "postinstall": "yarn migrate:prod && prisma generate"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.18",
    "@next-auth/prisma-adapter": "^1.0.3",
    "@prisma/client": "^4.1.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "1.8.1",
    "@svgr/webpack": "5.5.0",
    "@trpc/client": "^9.26.2",
    "@trpc/next": "^9.26.2",
    "@trpc/react": "^9.26.2",
    "@trpc/server": "^9.26.2",
    "framer-motion": "^6.5.1",
    "next": "12.2.1",
    "next-auth": "^4.10.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.7.7",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-query": "3.39.2",
    "react-redux": "8.0.1",
    "react-toastify": "8.0.3",
    "redux": "4.2.0",
    "redux-persist": "6.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "2.4.1",
    "superjson": "^1.9.1",
    "zod": "^3.17.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "18.0.0",
    "@types/nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "@types/prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "@types/react": "18.0.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.5",
    "@types/react-redux": "7.1.24",
    "@types/react-toastify": "4.1.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.0.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "eslint": "8.1.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^17.0.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.2.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.12.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.30.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "prisma": "^4.1.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.6",
    "typescript": "4.3.5",
    "vercel": "^27.2.0"
  }
}
```

Then in a component, I'm just doing what I'd usually do

```
import React from "react";
import type { NextPage } from "next";
import { faTimes } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";

const Home: NextPage = () => {
  return (
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTimes} color="#fff" size="1x" />
  );
};

export default Home;
```

The icon renders fine, it's the classes applied to the SVG, those closes don't seem to exist

like `fa-1x` which would usually apply `font-size: 1em;` to the element, is not being applied in my app.

I'm not sure if there is something specific I'm missing here?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import the FontAwesome css styles in `pages/_app.js`

```
import { config } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css'
config.autoAddCss = false

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}
```

See https://fontawesome.com/v5/docs/web/use-with/react#getting-font-awesome-css-to-work for more info

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Not sure why I've never had to do that before though.

Comment: Exactly. The need for this seems to have changed. A site was working fine w/ @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core v1.2.28. I "updated" it to 1.2.32, and the styles disappeared.